# how can I "unlink" files stored in SVN repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've got two sites in my local www folder, say site1.com and site2.com.

They are both stored in my SVN repo on the dev server, and I use tortoise SVN.

I've copied some files from one of the sites to another, but SVN now has these files linked together in the repo.

E.g. if I update main.css on site1 and commit it, when I update main.css on site2, it gets the changes I made in site1.

How can I unlink these files again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue I was having by doing an export of the working copy to another folder, then removing the site from the svn and re-importing it from scratch.

Still hoping there is a better way to resolve the problem though (I now know to use export if I want to copy a file or a directory from a working copy).

Answer (score 1):

How did you copy the files from site1 to site2 ? If you use the "svn copy" command line, it should do what you want (copy the current version of the file to a new location but from now on they have separate lifes).

Alternatively, you can copy the files normally and then do a 'svn add', though that is less efficient.

If you do the second technique and copy whole directories, know that you will also copy svn's metadata and that is sure to cause problems.

Now to unlink the files, I would guess that a 'svn remove' of one of them would do the trick.  Then re-copy it as explained above.